# Next-Gen Display Splash Screen | C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Is there anyway to display a splash screen without the window? Like just the image pops up for a few seconds, then after that shows a dialog box asking the player if he/she wants to create a new project or open one. I know, two questions in one. I am using Visual Studio right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean like:

Code Blocks:
[image: Code Blocks]

Photoshop:
[image: Photoshop]

Or even, the very program you're using, Visual Studio:
[image: Visual Studio]

Other ones include anything in the Adobe suite, and anything in the office suite, just off the top of my head.

So, obviously the answer is yes. The way to do this is to create a borderless window. With C++, this seems to be a bit difficult. I would highly suggest sticking to a rectangle splash screen, unless you want to handle the paint events to draw whatever is below you, which is a pain.

I found a how-to [over here at Programmers Heaven](http://programmersheaven.com/discussion/102833/this-is-how-to-create-a-borderless-window), which is below so it's also on this site per SO guidelines.

The other option, is to simply use C#, which makes this kind of thing really easy.

---

First Create a window with the `WS_POPUP` flag

Also - When creating your window take into account the fact that the system will likely still want to draw the border and title bar etc... so calculate that into your window dimensions as follows

```
#define WINDOW_WIDTH 300 // whatever size you need
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 256

// Calculate the proper size for the window given a client 
DWORD dwFrameWidth = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXSIZEFRAME );
DWORD dwFrameHeight = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYSIZEFRAME );
DWORD dwMenuHeight = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYMENU );
DWORD gdwWindowXPos = ( GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXSCREEN ) - WINDOW_WIDTH ) / 2;
DWORD gdwWindowYPos = ( GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYSCREEN ) - WINDOW_HEIGHT ) / 2;
DWORD gdwWindowWidth = WINDOW_WIDTH + dwFrameWidth * 2;
DWORD gdwWindowHeight = WINDOW_HEIGHT + dwFrameHeight * 2 + dwMenuHeight;
```

You should then have something like this for your window creation:

```
HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0,
                           "Class Name",
                           "Window Name",
                           WS_POPUP, // and any other flags you need
                           gdwWindowXPos, // these just center the
                           gdwWindowYPos, // window on the screen
                           gdwWindowWidth, // Calculated width
                           gdwWindowHeight, // and height
                           NULL, // Parent window
                           NULL, // Menu (don't want one)
                           hInst, // hInstance
                           NULL // Other Parameters
);
```

... Right ....

The next thing is to set the window region, so that you only draw the area you're interested in by using `CreateRectRgn`, and `SetWindowRgn` like so:

```
HRGN hrgn = CreateRectRgn( 0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT );

SetWindowRgn( hwnd, hrgn, TRUE );
```

This clips the window to the size I wanted when I `#defined` `WINDOW_WIDTH` and `WINDOW_HEIGHT`

Comment: For the transparency effect that you see in splash screens like Adobe Photoshop's, you can also just display a rectangular image with transparent portions, add the `WS_EX_LAYERED` extended style to your window, and call either the `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` or `UpdateLayeredWindow` function. Probably easier than dealing with regions.

Comment: @misterVivid, if this solved your question, be sure to click the checkmark below the up/down arrows at the top left of the post.